# Bootsrap tooltip is not working when div container is duplicated

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui-tooltip, jquery-clone

div Clone_CompMulDet contain a tooltip, Its working perfectly, but whenever the div is duplicate tootltip is not working...

```
// start

<div class="col-xs-12 clone_cls_1" id="Clone_CompMulDet">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal Owner Name" name="vc_legal_owner" id="vc_legal_owner">
<a data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title="shipping costs will be calculated from this location">
<img src="../images/qn_icn.png">
</a>
<a class="plus" id="Clonemulti">Add New</a>
</div>

// end


// Div duplicate

$("#Clonemulti").click(function () {
   var $div = $('div[id^="Clone_CompMulDet"]:last');
   $new_comp.find('input:text,textarea').val('');
   var $new_comp = $div.clone();            
   $div.after($new_comp);   
 });
```

Comment: can you show the html of the duplicated div?

Comment: @NicholasNur mentioned it in my code between start  and  end

Comment: IDs need to be unique within an HTML document. If you are cloning elements that have IDs (or contain descendants with IDs), then you have to modify those IDs accordingly ... And then you might have to initialize the tooltip functionality on the clone specifically, I doubt this script is written to automatically recognize dynamically added elements.

Comment: @NicholasNur id is unique but class name is (clone_cls_1) is incrementing with each clone.